# Gem bundler disappeared from Ruby on Rails server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ruby-on-rails, gem

Linux (Ubuntu) Ruby on Rails WEBrick server was running fine last night. Woke up this morning and the computer I use to SSH on to my remote server had stalled. After rebooting I  attempted to restart the server process. When I did so, I was greeted with:

```
enter code here/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know what might have caused this, how to fix it, and how to prevent this from happening in future? Might it be a security issue? Surely this shouldn't be happening for no reason.

Comment: we need alot more info. what command gave you the error? `rails s`? `which rails`, `rvm`, `rbenv`, `which bundle`, `which gem`, `which ruby` etc, etc..

Comment: It's alright. I have a new rails install running now and fingers crossed it's all working fine.